# Counting in a Many-To-Many Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 4.1 Code First I have two objects with a many-to-many relationship:

```
 public class Article  
    {
        public int ID { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; } 
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Tag>  Tags { get; set; }
}

 public class Tag
        { 
            [Key]
            public string UrlSlug { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

I want to count the most common Tags applied to Articles. How do I do this in LINQ?

I tried the below code which only ordered the Tags:

```
  var tagsFromDb = db.Tags
                  .GroupBy(q => q.UrlSlug)
                  .OrderByDescending(gp => gp.Count())
                  .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand right you have a many-to-many relationship between articles and tags but the navigation property on the tag side is not exposed (there is no `ICollection<Article>` in `Tag`). I think in this case you have to start from the articles to get all used tags along with the information how often they are used in the articles:

```
var tagQuery = db.Articles
    .SelectMany(a => a.Tags)          // flat enumeration of all used tags
    .GroupBy(t => t, (k, g) => new    // k = key = Tag, g = group of same tags
    {
        Tag = k,                      // the tag
        Count = g.Count()             // how often does it occur in the articles
    })
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count); // most used tags first
```

If you want all tags sorted descending, call

```
var tagList = tagQuery.ToList();
```

If you just want the tag which is most often used in the articles, call

```
var mostUsedTag = tagQuery.FirstOrDefault();
```

In both cases the result is a collection/single object of an anonymous type which has the `Tag` and `Count` as members. If you just want the tag(s) and are not interested in the `Count` anymore you can project before apply `ToList` or `FirstOrDefault`: `tagQuery.Select(anonymous => anonymous.Tag)....`.

**Edit**

Just saw the Edit in your question. Now, when you have an `Article` collection in the `Tag` entity it is easier:

```
var tagQuery = db.Tags
    .Select(t => new
    {
        Tag = t,                      // the Tag
        Count = t.Articles.Count()    // just count the number of artices
                                      // the tag is used in
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count); // most used tags first
```